# How do you delete all data stored from Sembast db on web? Flutter

Tags: flutter-web, sembast

In my app which run both on device and web I use sembast for the local db, and when I want to wipe all data to start testing on a fresh db, on Android I simply use the Android menu, select my app and delete all data. How do you do it for the data generated when the app is run on Chrome? Many thanks and sorry for the naive question lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web, sembast is storing data in an Indexed DB database (with the same name than the sembast db name). You should be able to find this database in the Chrome developer tools, in the Applications tab, then Storage, then IndexedDB. Select the database and choose the button "Delete database".